# Article GEO gives counts that are not integers. Should UMI counts be integers?

Tags: scrnaseq, umi, geo

I thought that `UMI` counts are always integers, but when I opened several datasets provided by `GEO` I got confused because in some articles they provide `counts` that are supposedly non-normalized raw `UMI` count values, but they are not integers. For instance: [GSM2043231](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2043231) or [GSE77067](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE77067)

Could anyone clarify, what these people mean by `abundance measurements`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data processing section doesn't mention using UMIs at all, so it's likely there were none (whether they'll be present depends on how the libraries are made, with lower throughput methods being less likely to include them). The values are stated as being expected counts from [RSEM](https://deweylab.github.io/RSEM/), which is why they're not always integers.